# Why do I use a star for pointers when printing chars but not strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Alright I've got two questions, both based on the same snippet of sample code provided by my professor:

```
char arr[3][3] = {
        { '0', '1', '2' },
        { '3', '4', '5' },
        { '6', '7', '\0' }
};
char* base = &arr[0][0], *a = &arr[0][0];
a = base + 5;
printf("base=%d a=%d", base, a);
printf("*a = %c ", *a); 
a = base + 3;
printf("row = %s", a); // HERE!
```

So in the line I marked, we reference a instead of *a. This is what I don't understand. Isn't `a` a number? I understand that a string knows to just go ham on an array of characters until it hits a null terminator, but I don't understand why you don't need the star. Is a not just some long ass number? Does formatting it with %s make it know to follow the pointer, and if so, why doesn't %c do the same? Why does using the star when trying to print with %s cause an exception?

Comment: You declared `a` to be a `char*`, not a number.

Comment: when printing pointers, one should use `%p`

Comment: a is a number, in the sense that this number represents a location in memory - memory just gets counted. %s understands a number as a location in memory to count to, then print everything from that location on, interpret the found data as a character, until it hits a location in memory that is a Null terminator. %c prints a single character, it doesn't keep printing until it hits a Null terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different format specifiers tell `printf` how to interpret the argument:

- `%d` treats it as a normal integer. Passing it a pointer (`a`) results in undefined behavior, but is likely to print part of the pointer's address (a large number)
- to properly print the address of a pointer, use `%p` instead of `%d`.
- `%c` treats it as a character (but still takes an `int`; `char` is implicitly converted). Your code passes `*a`, which is indeed a character: the `char` that `a` points to.
- `%s` treats it as a pointer to the beginning of a null-terminated string of `char`s. Your code passes `a`, which is that: a pointer-to-`char`. It will follow the pointer along, printing characters until it hits `\0`.

So the type of the expression `a` is pointer-to-`char`, while `*a` is `char`. If you use a `char` with `%s`, `printf` will try to use it as a pointer. Since this "points to" a memory location between `0x00` and `0xFF`, it will give you a segmentation fault for invalid memory access.

Comment: Not mine, but `%d` expects an `int`, passing a pointer without a proper cast invokes undefined behavior.  Pointer values can be printed with `%p` with a cast to `(void*)` or `%llu` with a cast to `(unsigned long long)`.  Furthermore, `%c` expects an `int`, which the `char` is implicitly converted to as per the vararg calling convention.

Comment: Fantastic answer, idk why people are down voting you. Thank you, by the way, this has cleared up quite a bit for me.

Comment: (I'm not the biggest fan of my professor's teaching style either lol)

Comment: Idk why you got so many downvotes, either... people on Stackoverflow can be pretty intolerant of learners.

Answer (score 3):

The `%s` format specifier takes a pointer and prints the string of characters it points to stopping at a zero byte. If you dereference a pointer to a character, all you get is a single character, exactly what `%c` needs.

Comment: *stopping at NULL* -> stopping at the null byte.